# How to dockerize monolith app with multiple separated projects?

Tags: docker, containers, dockerfile

i want to use docker image of my monolith application to test my app after commiting changes. I have one web-app project and many library projects (not application project!) in separated solutions that output of these projects will copy to a path that application's bin placed and make my app executable.

my source code structure is like this:

```
|--Master_Web_App.sln
|     |
|     app.csproj
|
|--projectA.sln
|      | 
|      projectA-1.csproj 
|      | 
|      projectA-2.csproj 
| 
|--projectB.sln 
      | 
      projectB-1.csproj 
      | 
      projectB-2.csproj
```

after building each project i copy its output to the physical path that website defined:

```
wwwroot
|--app
    |
    bin
      |
      app.dll
      projectA-1.dll
      projectA-2.dll
      projectB-1.dll
      projectB-2.dll
```

i created a base docker image to run my application.
 when a change occured in a specific project (ex projectA-1) i want to create a single docker image `FROM baseIamge` that only copies projectA-1's output to destination folder.

Assumptions:

1. i should have one single docker image for projects changes. (because
   i have a single-monolith app)
2. projects placed separated but part of
   a single web app.
3. i want create image only include changes from base
   image.

**what is the best practice to handle it??**

i thougt about creating a *Dockerfile* in root of each project and create a tool to merge all these Dockerfiles (every time changes commited and developer selected changed projects) and make a single-but-multi-staged Dockerfile!
so result of `Docker Build` will be an image included selected projects output and will `COPY` dlls to base image. but i'm not sure that generating Dockerfile text programtically is a good approach.

Comment: Maybe use docker-compose and place the docker-compose file on the top folder? The in the docker-compose file build the different projects and at the end copy the necessary files to the main image? Not sure if it would work but may be easier than trying to build the docker files every time.

Comment: i already have docker-compose to orchestrate other services(cache server, db, ...) with web container but i looking for a way to build my web image containing changed projects. according to your answer i don't know how to build all projects images in compose file then copy result to base and remove those intermediate images!

Answer (score 1):

You will have complex matrix of project version during development.

But one approach could be to pass project version/branch as parameters to docker build process. Create custom docker build process where you can build multiple projects as separate docker images one per project. For application docker image, `Dockerfile` use multistage builder and use all the project images to copy dlls in respective directories.

Separate images like:

```
|--Master_Web_App.sln
|     |
|     app.csproj -> app-dockerimage
|
|--projectA.sln
|      | 
|      projectA-1.csproj  -> projectA-1-dockerimage
|      | 
|      projectA-2.csproj  -> projectA-2-dockerimage
| 
|--projectB.sln 
      | 
      projectB-1.csproj  -> projectB-1-dockerimage 
      | 
      projectB-2.csproj  -> projectB-2-dockerimage
```

Main docker image:

```
# app docker image
FROM projectA-1-dockerimage as projectA-1
FROM projectA-2-dockerimage as projectA-2
FROM projectB-1-dockerimage as projectB-1
FROM projectB-2-dockerimage as projectB-2

FROM BASE_IMAGE

# other steps
#Build process app.dll

COPY FROM --projectA-1 wwwroot/app/bin/projectA-1.dll
COPY FROM --projectA-2 wwwroot/app/bin/projectA-2.dll
COPY FROM --projectB-1 wwwroot/app/bin/projectB-1.dll
COPY FROM --projectB-2 wwwroot/app/bin/projectB-2.dll
```

Comment: with this approach i have multiple images (for projects) + main docker image. but i don't need any of intermediate images. why should i create those images? if i place all projects dockerfile content to a a multi staged Main docker file i will have only one image and don't need to care about many project images. (in real world i have more than 100 projects for different modules).

Comment: Yes, then you can build all the packages in the main application Dockerfile also. But if one package is used among many applications then you have to copy same Dockerfile for package in many locations, leading to more issues.